# I want to print a square using the hash characters, javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to print a square using the hash character

```
 function square(num){
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < num; j++){
            console.log("#");
        }
        console.log(" ");
    }
    }square(2);
```

/* my output is:
"#"
"#"

"#"
"#"

instead of:
"##"
"##"
*/

Answer (score 2):

Creating a function named square to return a square pattern.Using squareArray as the solution array and result string to store the value for each inner loop.Finally, using join to convert array to string.

```js
function square(num) {
  const squareArray = [];
  let result;
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    result = "";
    for (let j = 0; j < num; j++) {
      result += "#";
    }
    squareArray.push(result);
  }
  return squareArray.join("\n");
}
console.log(square(2));
console.log(square(4));
console.log(square(6));
```

Answer (score 2):

Every time you `console.log()`, the console will print a new line. You need to add each row to one line like this:

```js
function square(num){
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
    let row = ''
        for(j = 0; j < num; j++){
            row+='#'
        }
        console.log(row+" ");
    }
}
square(4);
```

Comment: @Christopher Maphakane Please accept the answer if it solved your problem. Thanks